# SPI state not getting updated

Tags: stm32, spi

I am using STM32L496 microcontroller where I am initialising hspi3 as follows -

```
void MX_SPI3_Init()
{
    SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi3;

    /* SPI3 parameter configuration*/
    hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
    hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
    hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
    hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    hspi3.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
    hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
    hspi3.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
    hspi3.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
    if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

Inside my `HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3)` function, `hspi3` does not give any error code and it goes to `hspi->State = HAL_SPI_STATE_READY;`
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2gbk.png). But in the watch window, the `hspi3` state does not get updated; it remains at `HAL_SPI_STATE_RESET`. Hence, when I try to send some data using SPI as shown below, it fails -

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    static uint16_t sinTableIndex = 0;
    uint8_t data_on_spi[3];
    SysTime_mainFunction();
    if (getOperatingState() == CONTROL){
            data_on_spi[0]=sinTable[sinTableIndex] & MASK_LOW_BYTE;
            data_on_spi[1]=sinTable[sinTableIndex] & MASK_MID_BYTE;
            data_on_spi[2]=sinTable[sinTableIndex] & MASK_HIGH_BYTE;

            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_GPIO_Port,SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            if(HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi3, (uint8_t*)data_on_spi, 3,1) != HAL_OK)
            {
                    /* Transfer error in transmission process */
                    Error_Handler();
            }
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_GPIO_Port,SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
            sinTableIndex++;
            if (sinTableIndex >= maxTableSize)
            {
                    sinTableIndex = 0;
            }
    }
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);
}
```

When I `HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi3, (uint8_t*)data_on_spi, 3,1)` , it goes to error handler as it recognizes SPI state as `HAL_SPI_STATE_RESET`. 
Need help to understand why this is happening.

EDIT: I think the problem is that when I try to do `HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi3, (uint8_t*)data_on_spi, 3,1)`,LOCK remains unlocked even if `__HAL_LOCK(hspi)` is done.

Comment: Have you enabled the SPI clock? I can't find this in your code snippet. I sometimes have issues with my Watch Window that it is not showing the correct enumerated value. Try to find the memory address and recheck the value there. Which debugger are you using?

Comment: @A.R.C. - yes, the spi clock is enabled inside 'HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)' function as '__HAL_RCC_SPI3_CLK_ENABLE()'. I am using Keil uVision 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not transfer in the polling mode in the interrupt handlers.
   Why: because it consumes a lots of time. Those HAL functions relay on the tick value which is increased in the another interrupt which may not happen because of the interrupt priorities.

Comment: I've tried using 'HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA' and 'HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT' too in place of just 'HAL_SPI_Transmit', but it still enters the error code. However, when I use the SPI outside of the timer interrput, it seems to work fine.

Comment: I will say it another way: do not use the HAL transmit functions inside the interrupts.

Comment: Handling of interrupts in the portion of the STM32 HAL's concerning peripherals with sequential state is indeed quite complex.  Typically one should either handcraft the *entirety* of the ISR's, or look at *exactly* how the HAL *examples* do things, as the design of how this part of the HAL is supposed to work is at best "not intuitive".